# Oracle 11g data pump import job trying to create .DB files on the wrong drive

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I know absolutely nothing about Oracle until attempting this restore.  I have a .DMP file that I must restore.  After many failed attempts I have issued the command:
`alter system set DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST='E:\app\****\oradata\orcl';`
because the data pump job keeps trying to put files on a D:\ that I cannot write to (it's a DVD drive).  This DMP was created in Oracle 11g so that is what I've installed.

The error I get (many, many times) is like so:

```
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLESPACE "E:\APP\******\ORADATA\ORCL" DATAFILE 'D:\ORACLE\DATA\RRAEMR\LOGICIAN.DB' SIZE 251658240 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5242880 MAXSIZE 2097152000,'D:\ORACLE\DATA\RRAEMR\LOGICIAN_DATA_0002.DB' SIZE 10
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'D:\ORACLE\DATA\RRAEMR\LOGIC_IX.DB'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

When I look at ALL_DIRECTORIES there is no directory pointed at D:\, all point to E:\ or C:\ or X:.

I should add that during the data pump import wizard I have tried remapping the tablespace files to where I want them and I do see some files landing there.  I do not understand if this can be done for datafiles too.  It looks like it should, but when adding a row and clicking it no datafile name is supplied like it was for tablespaces.

How can I restore this dump on a different drive?

EDIT:
Ok I am firing off another data pump import job without doing any remapping and within the first few seconds the log file already has errors like:
Failing sql is:

```
CREATE UNDO TABLESPACE "UNDOTBS" DATAFILE 'D:\ORACLE\DATA\RRAEMR\UNDOTBS01.DB' SIZE 20971520 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5242880 MAXSIZE 2097152000,'D:\ORACLE\DATA\RRAEMR\UNDOTBS02.DB' SIZE 10485760 AUTOEXTEND ON NEX
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'D:\ORACLE\DATA\RRAEMR\TEMP_0003.DB'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So it's still wanting to put on the D:.  I captured the SQL for the job and here it is:

```
set scan off
set serveroutput on
set escape off
whenever sqlerror exit 
DECLARE
    s varchar2(1000); 
    h1 number;
    errorvarchar varchar2(100):= 'ERROR';
    tryGetStatus number := 0;
begin
    h1 := dbms_datapump.open (operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'FULL', job_name => 'IMP_SD_44-09_53_59', version => 'COMPATIBLE'); 
    tryGetStatus := 1;
    dbms_datapump.set_parallel(handle => h1, degree => 1); 
    dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'IMPORT-'||to_char(sysdate,'hh24_mi_ss')||'.LOG', directory => 'DMPDIR', filetype=>DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE); 
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'KEEP_MASTER', value => 1); 
    dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'RRA.DMP', directory => 'DMPDIR', filetype => 1); 
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1); 
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC'); 
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'REUSE_DATAFILES', value => 0); 
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION', value => 'REPLACE'); 
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES', value => 0);
    dbms_datapump.start_job(handle => h1, skip_current => 0, abort_step => 0); 
    dbms_datapump.detach(handle => h1); 
    errorvarchar := 'NO_ERROR'; 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN 
        IF ((errorvarchar = 'ERROR')AND(tryGetStatus=1)) THEN 
            DBMS_DATAPUMP.DETACH(h1);
        END IF;
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        NULL;
    END;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

Comment: That tablespace *name* looks... odd. It would probably be helpful to include the full import command you're using, along with some background on how the export was done, whether it was on the same server you're restoring too (seems unlikely from the path issues), and whether you are running the import remotely or on the server - bearing in mind that directory objects point to the server OS, not the client OS.

Comment: Oh, I think i misunderstood the remapping page in the wizard.  I pasted a path (that path it references) as the remapped value for a normally-named tablespace, like "L3".  I think I did that to myself.  I had the choice at the end of the wizard to see the whole PL/SQL command for this job but I didn't elect to copy it out.  Next time i will.

Comment: Not sure which client's wizard you're using, but you could take that generated SQL and manipulate it; you might find [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm) useful. Among other things to add will be [`REMAP_DATAFILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL926) calls, but exactly what remapping you need to do depends on your specific dump and environment (and the differences between that and the environment the export came from).

Comment: Also as it sounds like you're trying to import into an existing database (partly based on your `ALL_DIRECTORIES` reference), so you might not actually want a FULL import. You might only want specific schemas, for instance. Make sure you understand what is already in the database and what the import might change or replace. In other words - be very careful.